# Installing Leiningen for Clojure on Linux Mint 12

Tags: clojure, leiningen, linux-mint

Im a clojure beginner.I did the following steps as given on http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/clojure/brief-beginners-guide/development-env.html to setup Leiningen on my machine running Linux Mint 12.

```
cd ~/bin
wget https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein
chmod +x lein
lein self-install
```

But now when i run the following command :

```
lein new foobar
```

I get

```
The program 'lein' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install leiningen
```

I see a file leiningen-1.7.1-standalone.jar in ~/.lein/self-installs. Why am i being asked to install lein again using package manager even though i used the self-install method ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your `~/bin` directory is not on your `PATH`.

In your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`) you need to add something like:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```